# JoinColumn Mapped Attribute Returns Null in Spring Boot and JPA Entity Mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I recently started studying Java, and to improve my knowledge, I started performing tests with Spring Boot and JPA. I created an entity called Account to test all types of mapping between entities with JPA, and I'm encountering a problem.

My Account entity has the following settings:

```
package zone.nilo.startapi.models.entities.users;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import zone.nilo.startapi.models.entities.auth.Username;
import zone.nilo.startapi.models.entities.parameters.AccountType;
import zone.nilo.startapi.models.entities.parameters.Country;


import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@EnableJpaAuditing
@Table(name = "account", schema = "users")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID uuid;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_uuid")
    private Country country;
    private String fullName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_type_uuid")
    private AccountType accountType;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_uuid")
    private List<Document> document;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_uuid")
    private List<Mail> mails;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_uuid")
    private Username username;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private String createdBy;

    public Username getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(Username username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public List<Mail> getMails() {
        return mails;
    }

    public void setMails(List<Mail> mails) {
        this.mails = mails;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public AccountType getAccountType() {
        return accountType;
    }

    public void setAccountType(AccountType accountType) {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
    public List<Document> getDocument() {
        return document;
    }

    public void setDocument(List<Document> document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Account account)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(getUuid(), account.getUuid()) && Objects.equals(getCountry(), account.getCountry()) && Objects.equals(getFullName(), account.getFullName()) && Objects.equals(getAccountType(), account.getAccountType()) && Objects.equals(getDocument(), account.getDocument()) && Objects.equals(getMails(), account.getMails()) && Objects.equals(getUsername(), account.getUsername()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedAt(), account.getCreatedAt()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedBy(), account.getCreatedBy());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getUuid(), getCountry(), getFullName(), getAccountType(), getDocument(), getMails(), getUsername(), getCreatedAt(), getCreatedBy());
    }
}
```

I also have other entities to test. Here they are:

```
package zone.nilo.startapi.models.entities.parameters;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "country", schema = "parameters")
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID uuid;
    private String name;
    private String iso;
    private String currency;
    private String timezone;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private String createdBy;

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIso() {
        return iso;
    }

    public void setIso(String iso) {
        this.iso = iso;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getTimezone() {
        return timezone;
    }

    public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Country country)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(getUuid(), country.getUuid()) && Objects.equals(getName(), country.getName()) && Objects.equals(getIso(), country.getIso()) && Objects.equals(getCurrency(), country.getCurrency()) && Objects.equals(getTimezone(), country.getTimezone()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedAt(), country.getCreatedAt()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedBy(), country.getCreatedBy());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getUuid(), getName(), getIso(), getCurrency(), getTimezone(), getCreatedAt(), getCreatedBy());
    }
}


package zone.nilo.startapi.models.entities.parameters;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "account_type", schema = "parameters")
public class AccountType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID uuid;
    private UUID countryUuid;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private String createdBy;

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public UUID getCountryUuid() {
        return countryUuid;
    }

    public void setCountryUuid(UUID countryUuid) {
        this.countryUuid = countryUuid;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof AccountType that)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(getUuid(), that.getUuid()) && Objects.equals(getCountryUuid(), that.getCountryUuid()) && Objects.equals(getDescription(), that.getDescription()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedAt(), that.getCreatedAt()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedBy(), that.getCreatedBy());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getUuid(), getCountryUuid(), getDescription(), getCreatedAt(), getCreatedBy());
    }
}

package zone.nilo.startapi.models.entities.users;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import zone.nilo.startapi.models.entities.parameters.DocumentType;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(schema = "users")
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID uuid;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_type_uuid")
    private DocumentType documentType;
    private String description;
    @CreatedDate
    private String createdAt;
    private String createdBy;
    @Column(name = "account_uuid")
    private UUID accountUuid;

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public DocumentType getDocumentType() {
        return documentType;
    }

    public void setDocumentType(DocumentType documentType) {
        this.documentType = documentType;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public UUID getAccountUuid() {
        return accountUuid;
    }

    public void setAccountUuid(UUID accountUuid) {
        this.accountUuid = accountUuid;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Document document)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(getUuid(), document.getUuid()) && Objects.equals(getDocumentType(), document.getDocumentType()) && Objects.equals(getDescription(), document.getDescription()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedAt(), document.getCreatedAt()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedBy(), document.getCreatedBy()) && Objects.equals(getAccountUuid(), document.getAccountUuid());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getUuid(), getDocumentType(), getDescription(), getCreatedAt(), getCreatedBy(), getAccountUuid());
    }
}

package zone.nilo.startapi.models.entities.users;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "mail", schema = "users")
public class Mail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID uuid;
    @Column(name = "account_uuid")
    private UUID accountUuid;
    private String description;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private String createdBy;

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public UUID getAccountUuid() {
        return accountUuid;
    }

    public void setAccountUuid(UUID accountUuid) {
        this.accountUuid = accountUuid;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Mail mail)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(getUuid(), mail.getUuid()) && Objects.equals(getAccountUuid(), mail.getAccountUuid()) && Objects.equals(getDescription(), mail.getDescription()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedAt(), mail.getCreatedAt()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedBy(), mail.getCreatedBy());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getUuid(), getAccountUuid(), getDescription(), getCreatedAt(), getCreatedBy());
    }
}

package zone.nilo.startapi.models.entities.auth;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "username", schema = "auth")
public class Username {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID uuid;
    @Column(name = "account_uuid")
    private UUID accountUuid;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private String createdBy;

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public UUID getAccountUuid() {
        return accountUuid;
    }

    public void setAccountUuid(UUID accountUuid) {
        this.accountUuid = accountUuid;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Username username)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(getUuid(), username.getUuid()) && Objects.equals(getAccountUuid(), username.getAccountUuid()) && Objects.equals(getDescription(), username.getDescription()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedAt(), username.getCreatedAt()) && Objects.equals(getCreatedBy(), username.getCreatedBy());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getUuid(), getAccountUuid(), getDescription(), getCreatedAt(), getCreatedBy());
    }
}
```

Up to the part of mails, the mapping process seems to have worked normally. However, when I added one more attribute (username), the behavior doesn't seem to be the same as the other attributes that have mapping with JoinColumn. For some reason, the username attribute always returns empty, even if there's a record in the database. Can someone help me understand why this happens?

DDL of tables in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE users.account (
    uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    country_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
    full_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    account_type_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    created_by varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT account_pk PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
    CONSTRAINT account_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (country_uuid) REFERENCES parameters.country(uuid),
    CONSTRAINT account_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (account_type_uuid) REFERENCES parameters.account_type(uuid)
);

CREATE TABLE parameters.country (
    uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    iso varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    currency varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    timezone varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    created_by varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT country_pk PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
    CONSTRAINT country_unique_1 UNIQUE (name),
    CONSTRAINT country_unique_2 UNIQUE (iso)
);

CREATE TABLE parameters.account_type (
    uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    country_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
    description varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    created_by varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT account_type_pk PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
    CONSTRAINT account_type_unique UNIQUE (country_uuid, description),
    CONSTRAINT account_type_fk FOREIGN KEY (country_uuid) REFERENCES parameters.country(uuid)
);

CREATE TABLE users."document" (
    uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    document_type_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
    description varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    created_by varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    account_uuid uuid NULL,
    CONSTRAINT document_pk PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
    CONSTRAINT document_unique1 UNIQUE (document_type_uuid, description),
    CONSTRAINT document_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (account_uuid) REFERENCES users.account(uuid),
    CONSTRAINT document_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (document_type_uuid) REFERENCES parameters.document_type(uuid)
);

CREATE TABLE users.mail (
    uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    account_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
    description varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    created_by varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mail_pk PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
    CONSTRAINT mail_unique UNIQUE (description),
    CONSTRAINT mail_fk FOREIGN KEY (account_uuid) REFERENCES users.account(uuid)
);

CREATE TABLE auth.username (
    uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    account_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
    description varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    created_by varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT username_pk PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
    CONSTRAINT username_unique1 UNIQUE (description),
    CONSTRAINT username_unique2 UNIQUE (account_uuid),
    CONSTRAINT username_fk FOREIGN KEY (account_uuid) REFERENCES users.account(uuid)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your database model you have the foreign key in the `Username` table. It means that this is the owning side of the relationship. The table `Account` is the non-owning side of the relationship.

`@JoinColumn` annotation should be placed on the owning side.

**Solution**

```
public class Username {
// remove this is wrong:
// @Column(name = "account_uuid")
//    private UUID accountUuid;
// instead:
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid")
    private Account account;
}

public class Account {
// remove this is wrong:
//    @OneToOne
//    @JoinColumn(name = "account_uuid")
// instead:
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account")
    private Username username;
}
```

Based on: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one

Comment: I didn't quite understand. If JoinColumn should only be used on the owner side, why do country, mail, and documents work fine even using JoinColumn? Only the username is not okay.

Comment: What I said is only valid for one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score -1):

You muss add **referencedColumnName** in your **@JoinColumn** for an example:

```
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid")
    private Country country;
```

it means that you have account table that has one column named country_uuid that store country uuid for joining column

Comment: I believe that's not the case, since it works fine for all other attributes, except for the username.